# How to set headers in axios, ReactNative

Tags: react-native, api, axios

i build an application, React Native as Frontend and Django as Backend,
i use axios to take data from user then send it to backend it show error Request failed with status code 400

i have used Restful API that build with django and run the server locally,
so i think when i add headers to axios then the API request response without errors

so,How to set headers in axios

the user enter the data through form and send it to the backend

**Add.js page with form take data from user send it to the backend**

```
 import * as React from "react";
    import {View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput} from "react-native";
    import { COLORS, SIZES,FONTS} from '../styles/theme.js';
    import { FieldArray, Formik} from "formik";
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const AddScreen =()=>{
    
        const radioopt = [{},{},{},{}];
    
        const submit = (val) => {
            if(val.type == "" || val.category == "" || val.amount == ""){
                alert("Please Enter all details");
                return;
            }
            // 'http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/'
            axios.post('http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/', {
               
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": val?.type,
                    "category": val.category,
                    "amount": val?.amount,
                    // "owner" : "",
                    "date" : Date.now(),
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
    
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:COLORS.gray}}>
    
                <Formik
                initialValues={{type:'',category:'', amount:''}}
                onSubmit={(values)=>{submit(values)}}
                >
                    {(props)=>(
                        <View style={styles.whitecard}>
    
                            <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputstyle}
                            placeholder='type'
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('type')}
                            value={props.values.type}
                            />
                            
                            <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputstyle}
                            placeholder='category'
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('category')}
                            value={props.values.category}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputstyle}
                            placeholder='amount'
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('amount')}
                            value={props.values.amount}
                            keyboardType='numeric'
                            />
        
    
                            <View style={{margin:10,padding:0, backgroundColor:COLORS.pink, borderRadius:6}}>
                            <Button title='Submit' color='white' onPress={props.handleSubmit}></Button>
    
                            </View>
    
                        </View>
                    )}
                </Formik>
    
            </View>
        );
    
    
    
    }
    
  ...
export default AddScreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass an object with `headers` like documentation says: https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

so your request will be:

```
axios.post('http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/',{formData}, {
   //example with bearer token
   headers: {
     'Authentication': 'Bearer 89324u2jhjwe98'
   }
})
.then(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: an error show( Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm(), [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: formData])

Comment: Oh no, sorry, formData is just an example in case that you send some extra data.. here  https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro you can find the structure for post

Answer (score 2):

You can pass options on third argument. There you can add **headers** on post method like following:

```
axios.post('https://example.com', formData, { headers: 'content-type': 'text/json',...otherHeaders })
```